# Gitlab CI CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE: Permission denied

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am using GitLab Enterprise Edition 10.4.4-ee and here is some information about the same issue and it should be fixed: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2570.
Any solution to this other than rewriting the dockerfile as root user?

I got this error when I try to do this in gitlab-ci.

```
stages:
  - run_test_chrome

tests run:
  image: selenium/standalone-chrome
  stage: run_test_chrome
  script:
        -  echo test
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error then I upgraded the gitlab-runner (for me it was `sudo apt install gitlab-runner`) and the problem's gone